# NSInvalidArgumentException and the reason is reason: '-[UIViewController setDetailModal:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]){ 
    ViewController *details = [segue destinationViewController];       
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];    
    int row = [indexpath row];
    details.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_description[row],_IMAGES[row]];          
}}
```

this is my code, i am trying to do that page will moves to next page.
but its showing error like this below:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setDetailModal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b24ed0'

Comment: What is `DetailModal`? Is a property of your `ViewController`. I suggest you start it with a lower case for. I'd also rename `ViewController` to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the destination of your segue is a `UIViewController` rather than a `ViewController`.  In your storyboard, make sure that the class for that controller is set to `ViewController` in the identity inspector.

Comment: now its showing like this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5acc'

Comment: **And once again plz tell that reason @Phillip Mills**

Comment: Either you're calling `size` on a string variable (which doesn't have that method) or, more likely, you're trying to use an object that has been deallocated.  1)Use the breakpoint navigator to add an exception breakpoint.  2)Turn on zombies in your build scheme.  That should get you better error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.